Android target SDK 14 registerReceiver doesn't throw SecurityException
Android target SDK 14 context.registerReceiver doesn't throw SecurityException.
By the way, ContextCompat.registerReceiver throws.
In change logs for SDK 14, it's defined like for everyone.
Checked already with AppCompatActivity and default Activity on targets 34-35.
Is it expected behavior?
class MainActivity : Activity() {

    private val receiver = TimeSettingsChangedBroadcastReceiver()

    private val textView by lazy { findViewById<TextView>(R.id.main) }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter().apply {
            addAction(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED)
            addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED)
            addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED)
        })
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        unregisterReceiver(receiver)
    }

    inner class TimeSettingsChangedBroadcastReceiver :
        BroadcastReceiver() {

        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
            Log.d("RECEIVED_TAG", "onReceive: received")
        }
    }
}

Android API 34 documentation

The documentation that you link to states that a SecurityException will be thrown "if the receiver is not being registered for system broadcasts" (emphasis added). You are registering for system broadcasts.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-14#runtime-receivers-exported
What about this? And why behavior of ContextCompat is different from sdk?

"What about this?" -- that section echoes what I wrote above. "And why behavior of ContextCompat is different from sdk?" -- I do not know.
